# Get Pc Name in UWP windows App

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I am working on Universal Application for windows 8.x
Using the UserInformation Class I am able to find Domain, Principal, User Name....
But I need to get PC name like (ACER-PC) from system Information.

**Environment.MachineName,
NetworkInformation.GetHostNames()** these two are not working for me.

How can i get it in Universal windows Application.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the Universal Windows Platform (UWP) is only supported on Windows 10. For Windows 8.1, there was the notion of a "Universal app" that was the same source code built into two different packages one for Windows Store 8.1 and the other for Windows phone 8.1, but it has nothing really to do with the "Universal Windows Platform". In fact, in a UWP app you cannot use `UserInformation` at all. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.aspx) for details. You can only get limited information from `User` for privacy reasons in a UWP.

By design most system-specific information is hidden in both Windows 8.1 Store apps and Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps which is why `Environment.MachineName` fails. You can use the `EasClientDeviceInformation` class, the `AnalyticsInfo` class, and the `User` class to get some information but not "Domain", "Principle", or "User name".

*So the real question is: Why do you want the machine name and what do you think you need to use it for*?

Comment: I am building  "Universal app".

Comment: need to get Computer Name from Computer Properties window.

Comment: EasClientDeviceInformation class will only provide info about windows phone 8.x but I need info from windows store 8.x...    Is there any other way to get it..... except Environment.MachineName, NetworkInformation.GetHostNames()

Comment: No, which is why ``EasClientDeviceInformation`` was added to UWP for Windows 10.

Comment: There are a number of 'feature holes' in Windows 8.x Store that are addressed for Windows 10 UWP to make it easier to write a wider array of software. Therefore, my first recommendation would be to look at writing a UWP app for Windows 10 devices and if needed a Windows phone 8.1 app. Both of those platforms have ``EasClientDeviceInformation``.